# Removing the first part from a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I need to get rid of the first part of a string.

examples:

```
1 - I'm some text
2 - Another text
45 - More text
5000 - Yet another text
```

`str.Substring(3, str.Length-10)` wouldn't solve it, since the digits at the beginning have different length.
Is there a workaround to just keep the text after the dash?
Btw, the structure of the string will always look like the examples above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to first get the index of the - character in each string and then use that index in the subsequent call to `Substring`:

```
var i = str.IndexOf('-');
var part = str.Substring(i + 1).Trim();
```

Comment: Output = "- I'm some text" and i want it to be "I'm some text"

Comment: @MrMAG - Sorry. Forgot to add 1 to the index of the -. Updated.

Comment: @MrMAG Note that, with the `+ 1`, if the original string `str` contains no `-` character, the result `part` will be equal to the original `str`. (Possibly trimmed for spaces in the ends, though.)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by character '-' and take the second item:

```
string Result = str.Split('-')[1].Trim();
```

Comment: This will only work if the string doesn't contain another - somewhere after the first.

Comment: Justin Niessner is right. It will happen sometimes, that the string contains more than one dash. But thank you too. :)